# can I use any docker image as a base image or is there a predefined base images?

Tags: docker

If I want to build a docker image, 
I need to base on a docker base image.

All the example I found are based on top of official images.
Can I base my image on other docker user images ?

Comment: You can build an image locally then reference that image as a base on other local builds. For example, I have a custom base dev node image that I use for my projects which adds extra debugging tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FROM` line in your Dockerfile can point to any image. It may be an upstream image from the Docker hub, one on any other registry server including one you self host, or it may be another image you've built locally on your own docker build host. Lastly, it may be `FROM scratch` which starts without any base image, and is used by other base images at some point in their history.